# Has include_docs been removed from the Couchbase Node SDK?

Tags: node.js, sdk, couchbase, couchbase-view

In the Couchbase SDK 2.x for Node, you could use `.include_docs(true)` on a `ViewQuery` to retrieve the matched documents alongside the data emitted by the view.  I don't see this option in the 3.x SDK, nor can I find it in the documentation.  Has it been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in fact was in SDK 2.x as you remember, it is not available in Couchbase Node SDK 3.x. So yes, it has been removed.